# Is it possible to reset NSURLConnection after providing credentials?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am calling a REST service that requires basic auth and I respond to the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` delegate OK.

```objectivec
NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:self.user password:self.password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
[[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
[credential release];
```

The credentials are valid for the Session but I would like for my App to be able to switch between servers and therefore need to "reset" the Session so it asks again for a challenge.

I can of course try the option of not storing the credentials for the session and supplying them for each call but this does not seem like a good idea.

Any ideas would be appreciated!